# How to open a PDF file by clicking on it in TreeView

Tags: python, tkinter, treeview

How do I open a file (ex. PDF) when I click on the row identify by its ID?

I'm trying to make the treeview that uses a GUI to better access and open these PDFs, but I can't figure out how to actually open files using anything but a button. Can someone please tell me how to use these to find a filepath and open a pdf? Thanks

the idea is basically is to open the pdf local file according to its ID in the treeview

[image]

```
from tkinter import E, N, Frame, IntVar, LabelFrame, LEFT, RIGHT, BOTTOM, StringVar, Label, Button, END, Toplevel, Entry, Tk, font, Menu
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk, Spinbox

class PRODUCTOS():
    base_datos = "clientes_productos.db"
    resultado = 0.00 #valor x defecto self.resultado
   
    def __init__(self,root):

        self.wind = root #ventana completa
        self.wind.title('Facturacion principal')
        self.wind.geometry("850x525")
        
        #Las divisiones de la ventana, caja 1 arriba, caja 2 abajo
        caja1 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text="", font=("Calibri",14), padx=2, pady=2)#aleja lo q se encuentra dentro
        caja2 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text="Facturas", font=("Calibri",12), padx=1, pady=1)
        caja3 = LabelFrame(self.wind, text="", font=("Calibri",12), padx=2, pady=2)
        caja1.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10, ipady=10, ipadx=5)#pady = aleja a la caja 2, X aleja de la esquina derecha
        caja2.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10, ipady=100, ipadx=5)#ipady alarga el labelframe
        caja3.pack(fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=10, ipady=30, ipadx=5)


        #los encabezados del cuadro blanco arriba
        #los encabezados del cuadro blanco arriba
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas = ttk.Treeview(caja2, columns=("1","2","3","4","5","6","7"), show="headings", height=10)#Height largo del Scrollbar
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.pack(side=LEFT)#scrollbar
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.place(x=0, y=0)#scrollbar
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("1", text="Nro_Fact.")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("2", text="ID-Cliente")
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.heading("3", text="Nombre del Cliente")


        #tamano de las columnas vertical
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("1", width=70)# width= anchura, minwidth = lo minimo de esa anchura
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("2", width=70)
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column("3", width=258)
        #horizontal
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.column('#0', width=50, minwidth=100)#Yscrollbar1


        #self.consulta_facturas() #llamada a la TABLA
        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.bind("<Double 1>", self.on_double_click)
        #self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.bind('<Double-Button-1>', self.on_double_click)


        #scrollbar VERTICAL lado derecho cuadro blanco 
        yscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(caja2, orient="vertical", command=self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.yview)
        yscrollbar.pack(side=RIGHT,fill="y")

        #scrollbar HORIZONTAL lado derecho cuadro blanco
        xscrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(caja2, orient="horizontal", command=self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.xview)
        xscrollbar.pack(side=BOTTOM,fill="x")

        self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.configure(yscrollcommand=yscrollbar.set, xscrollcommand=xscrollbar.set)


    def on_double_click(self, event):
        iid = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.focus() # get the iid of the selected item
        tags = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.item(iid, 'tags') # get tags attached
        print(iid)
        if 'pdf' in tags:
            text = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.item(iid, 'text') # get the text of selected item
            print(text)

            
if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk()
    product = PRODUCTOS(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What happens when you run your code? Have you done any debugging to figure out why it's not working? It's not clear what problem you are having trouble with. Do you not understand how bindings work, or do you not understand how to open the file?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74533389/8512262) help at all? I know that question is about opening links from a `Treeview` but the basic idea is similar. You could, as an example, use `os.startfile()` to open the PDF in your computer's default viewer.

Comment: @BryanOakley when I run the program, it gives me the ID of the row, my problem is, I dont know how to set a route of my desktop to compare  the local  pdf id between the id in the treeview to open that PDF.

Comment: From the image, the name of the PDF is the row ID, so you can construct the full pathname using the folder where the PDF is and the row ID. I wonder why you need help.

Comment: @acw1668 what I want is, when I do click on the row 197 the on_double_click opens that pdf 197 so on and so on, do you understand now?

Comment: Yes I understand. As I said you know the name of the PDF and also the folder where the PDF is, then you can construct the full pathname of the PDF file.  Is the problem that you don't know how to open a PDF even you have the full pathname? If yes, the link mentioned in JRiggles' comment may help.

Comment: @acw1668 ok thanks I will see it

Answer (score 1):

thanks for helping me out
its done!

```
def treeview_click(self, event):
        iid = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.focus() # id 
        name = self.cuadro_blanco_facturas.item(iid)["values"][2] #column name
        espacio = " "
        file = os.startfile(f"facturas\\{iid}{espacio}{nombre}.pdf")
```